# How do I use XSLT to put a node set into an attribute value?

Tags: xslt

I have an xsl template that I want to call to put into an HTML node attribute:

```
<xsl:variable name="onClickJavaScript">
  <xsl:call-template name="GetOnClickJavaScript" />
</xsl:variable>
<a id="123">
  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
    <xsl:value-of select="$onClickJavaScript" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

My problem is that the call-template returns a node set and the attribute value wants to be a string.  I can't seem to find any way to transform the node set into a string that works.

I have tried changing the value-of line to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$onClickJavaScript/text()" />
```

But it complains that it needs to return a node set and that does not (which is what I was hoping, without the complaining part).

In the Visual Studio debugger I can see that $onClickJavaScript is a NodeSet with a single dimension and item.  My string is buried in there, but not accessible :-(.

UPDATE...

When I call my template, it goes through a big case statement and calls another template.  This other template has a `<xsl:choose>` and it goes down the following path in this case:

```
<xsl:when test="$isPrimary='true'">         
  <!-- Just provide the onclick event JavaScript -->
  <xsl:value-of select='concat($launchMethod, "(this, &apos;", $id, "&apos;, &apos;", $nodeid, "&apos;, &apos;", $instanceid, "&apos;)")' />
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Can you provide an input document and a reduced sample XSLT file? `xsl:value-of` would return the string value of the node-set.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and suggested solution.

Comment: The odd part is that I get the values that I want, but since they are in a different format (node set vs. text) they are not handled properly.  When using Visual Studio to debug this I can use the developer toolbar and see that my anchor tag has the necessary value for the onclick handler, but it is just not interpreted properly.  It's almost as if there are control characters in there.  If I modify the onclick hanlder to add a character, the debugger "fixes" things and they work (for that session only, of course).

Comment: You say: "The other template has `a`" -- My answer is that you shouldn't have any element -- remove the `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that the call-template
>   returns a node set and the attribute
>   value wants to be a string. I can't
>   seem to find any way to transform the
>   node set into a string that works.

**The problem is in the code you haven't shown**.

In fact, I cannot reproduce this problem at all.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="onClickJavaScript">
      <xsl:call-template name="GetOnClickJavaScript" />
    </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="onClickJavaScript2">
      <xsl:call-template name="GetOnClickJavaScript2" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <a id="123">
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
        <xsl:value-of select="$onClickJavaScript" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
    <a id="123456">
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
        <xsl:value-of select="$onClickJavaScript" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="GetOnClickJavaScript">Hello</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="GetOnClickJavaScript2">
  <a>Hello</a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used) produces its output without any errors**:

```
<a id="123" onclick="Hello"/>
<a id="123456" onclick="Hello"/>
```

Comment: I updated the question to have a snippet from my template I am calling.  It just does <xsl:value-of select"concat(...)" /> to give me the data I want.  Is there a way to change that to output something else?  Or maybe the template needs to have some declaration to indicate its output is different?

Comment: I marked this as the answer because of the useful help.  What happened, though, was that I was chasing the wrong problem.  This runs on a SharePoint page and I didn't realize that it was doing some Javascript that was apparently affecting the ability for any onclick event to fire.  After sleeping on it, I decided to test with a hard-coded "alert" in the onclick.  This wouldn't fire, but if I removed the ID from the anchor tag it fired.

Comment: FYI, The rest of my morning was spent figuring out that I did need to call my template outside of my <xsl:attribute> node.  I'm not sure why that is the case, but it was.  So, I have it in a variable and all is well (finally).  Thanks for everyone's attempt to help me!

Answer (score 2):

With the information provided, your first sample should work, i.e.

```
<xsl:attribute name="onclick">
  <xsl:value-of select="$onClickJavaScript" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

should insert an `onclick` attribute with the (string) value of `$onClickJavaScript`.

You can even simplify your XSLT by using an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates):

```
<a id="123" onclick="{$onClickJavaScript}">...</a>
```

Or get rid of the variable and call the template inside the attribute node:

```
<xsl:attribute name="onclick">
  <xsl:call-template name="GetOnClickJavaScript" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: This most probably will not solve the problem. The OP's problem is that `$onClickJavaScript` is of type RTF and needs the `xxx:node-set()` extension function to be applied in order to convert it to a normal tree.

Comment: As Dimitre points out, only first two solutions will work with mixed content, but maybe not in the way OP wants to.

Comment: In my case the anchor tag already has a lot more logic around attribute values so I pretty much need to use <xsl:attribute>.  I separated it into a variable as I was trying different things and realize that I could probably remove that once I understand this better.

Comment: @Kirk-Liemohn: I changed my answer -- the alleged problem cannot be reproduced at all -- see a working example. So, this emphasizes even more the need for you to provide sufficient to repro information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this either... here's what I tried, the onclick on the a gets "foo(this, '3', 'test')". What else is different? What is the result-tree-fragment that you're trying to call xsl:value-of on?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="onclick-val">
    <xsl:call-template name="foo" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
      <xsl:value-of select="$onclick-val" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="foo">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="false()">
      false
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="callme" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="callme">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="true()">
      <xsl:value-of select='concat("foo", "(this, &apos;", "3", "&apos;, &apos;", "test", "&apos;)")' />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      false
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```